# echo limit to eclipse php? Is this an out of memory issue?

Tags: php, eclipse, memory, limit, echo

So i managed to create some lovely php code that uses file_get_contents for bing, yahoo, and google on Eclipse. Now to view the contents I retrieved (5 results per search engine), I created a double nested for loop to echo out everything in a readable form.

This worked when I had just yahoo and google displaying their respective 5 results. An example would be below on what would display based on the search query:
1) Title: The Devil Went Down to Georgia - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
Summary: "The Devil Went Down to Georgia" is a song written and performed by the Charlie Daniels Band and released on their 1979[1] album Million Mile Reflections. ...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Devil_Went_Down_to_Georgia

Now this didn't work when I had all three search engines to display their results. So when I debugged through it, the program halted after Bing echoed its third result (the other two echoed their 5). I tried rearranging and I get the same issues. I even had it where I increased the results to 20 and had only yahoo display its results which the program stopped after the 14th result.

Now I created something else to test what is going on shown below:
while($a < 50){
echo $a." Summary: free mp3 download, Million Mile Reflections [UK], mp3, mp3s, free, mp3 download, mp3 dowload, free Mp3 downloads, mp3 music download, music search, mp3 search,mp3 music\n";
$a++;
}

When I debugged through this repeating echo code, it became stuck after line 20. I am not sure why. Is there a limit to what I can echo? Am I out of memory? If so, then how do I resolve it? I have 512MB of RAM and have about 20GB of HD space remaining. I tried looking around in Eclipse and I am failing to find some functionality to increase memory usage or clearing a cache or whatever.

Comment: OKay, serious input time.  Errors?  None?  Let's see if there are any lurking.  Put these at the top of your script: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Made a HUGE mistake. I have 1GB of RAM. Not 512. Got it confused with my linux machine.

In any case I ran that line of code and nothing is displayed other than this:
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.14 ZendServer
Set-Cookie: ZendDebuggerCookie=127.0.0.1%3A10000%3A0||004|77742D65|1001; path=/
Content-type: text/html

0 Summary: free mp3 download, Million Mile Reflections [UK], mp3, mp3s, free, mp3 download, mp3 dowload, free Mp3 downloads, mp3 music download, music search, mp3 search,mp3 music

Well it goes on for another 19 repeats before halting.

Comment: I also have this at the top of the file and outside the php tags:
vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

I went through debugging and after it froze executing the 21st echo, I waited to see if anything happened. I don't think this is related but the debugging session terminated with this error:
Launch Error - Session Terminated:
Error while communicating with the debugger.
Possible causes:
1) The Zend Debugger was not properly installed
2) You are not using the latest Zend Debugger.

Comment: Can you try *timing* how long it takes before timing out?  You might have a [max_execution_time](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) set.

Comment: okay. just below the <?php is this: ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(-1); set_time_limit(15);

i'm running it and nothing happens. it's after I press the terminate button that everything is dumped to a certain point.

Comment: Heck I even commented EVERYTHING out with the exception of this block of code:
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(-1); set_time_limit(15);
$a = 0;
while($a < 999){
echo $a."\n";
$a++;
}
?>

It will print 997 echo lines, increment $a to 998, and repeat at the top. When it executes the 998th echo line, everything stops and the "cursor" that shows which line of code will be executed disappears. I have to terminate in order to see the debug output. I am hoping this is just with the echo output and won't be affected in the browser output when i start creating html tags.

Comment: This sound really fishy.  What debug engine are you using?  xdebug?  Zend's?

Comment: Zend's. I mentioned it above a while ago. When I waited long enough in my debug session, it would terminate and give me a Zend debugger prompt

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with Eclipse's debug handling and Zend's debug functions to be much help.  I use Komodo and xdebug...

Comment: well can you do this at least if you have the time: can you take that loop statement of $a in php and see if you can replicate it? if it freezes on you then i know it isn't just my computer but the program itself.

Comment: Not having the same environment, I would not be able to replicate this problem in a way that makes it a real troubleshooting step.

Comment: Okay. Hopefully there will be some resolution to this or a reason why I have this problem